# How to insert string values into a empty created py-spark data frame?

Tags: string, dataframe, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I want to create a empty spark data frame and add data into it, when I try doing as below I am getting an error:-

```
cars = 1
type= 'Sedan'
bike= 2
type2 = 'Racer'
count =100
result=spark.createDataFrame([('cars', cars),('car_type', type),('bike', bike),('bike_type', type2), ('count',count)],['Info','Record'])
empty = sqlContext.createDataFrame(sc.emptyRDD(), result.schema)
df = empty.unionAll(result).show()
display(df)
```

Error:-

```
TypeError: field Observation: Can not merge type <class 'pyspark.sql.types.LongType'> and <class 'pyspark.sql.types.StringType'>
```

Expected Output:-

```
+--------------------+-----------+
|         Info       |     Record|
+--------------------+-----------+
|    Cars            |          1|
|    Car_type        |      sedan|
|    Bike            |          2|
|    Bike_type       |      Racer|
|    Count           |        100|
+--------------------+-----------+
```

Comment: column can only have one type, in this case string. use `cars = '1'`, `bike = '2'`, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A column should only have one type. If you can't guarantee that it is better to create the dataframe with a schema passed.

You can create a dataframe like this,

```
schema = StructType([StructField('Info', StringType(), True),
                     StructField('Record', StringType(), True)])

data = [('cars', 1), ('car_type', 'Sedan'), ('bike', 2), ('bike_type', 'Racer'), ('count', 100)]

df = sc.createDataFrame(data, schema)

df.show()

+---------+------+
|     Info|Record|
+---------+------+
|     cars|     1|
| car_type| Sedan|
|     bike|     2|
|bike_type| Racer|
|    count|   100|
+---------+------+
```